# NSString under ARC may cause -[__NSArrayM length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance?

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I am using `NSData` to send and receive messages such as text, picture and voice. In order to differ the type of message, I append a header. When messages arrive, I assign the `NSString` object with the header and use `[header isEqualToString:@"txt"]` to determine different operations.

This is my method to handle the arrived message:

```
int msgarrvd (void *context, char *topicName, int topicLen, MQTTClient_message *message)
{
    void *payloadptr = message->payload;
    int payLoadLen = message->payloadlen;
    NSLog(@"%d", payLoadLen);

    NSMutableArray *msgArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSData *dataHeader = [NSData dataWithBytes:payloadptr length:3];
    NSStringEncoding strEncode = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
    NSString *header = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataHeader encoding:strEncode];
    NSLog(@"header:%@", header);

        if ([header isEqualToString:@"txt"]) {
            // text message
            NSData *content = [NSData dataWithBytes:payloadptr length:payLoadLen];
            NSString *msgContent = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:content encoding:strEncode];
            NSString *subStr = [msgContent substringFromIndex:3];
            [msgArray addObject:subStr];
        }
        if ([header isEqualToString:@"pic"]) {
          // pic message
        }
        if ([header isEqualToString:@"voc"]) {
            // voice message
            NSMutableData *voiceData = [NSMutableData data];
            [voiceData appendData:[NSData dataWithBytes:payloadptr length:payLoadLen]];
            [voiceData replaceBytesInRange:NSMakeRange(3, payLoadLen) withBytes:payloadptr];
            NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
            NSString *voicePath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingString:@"sound.wav"];
            [fm createFileAtPath:voicePath contents:voiceData attributes:nil];
            NSURL *voiceURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:voicePath];
            [msgArray addObject:voiceURL];

        NSMutableDictionary *myDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        if ([header isEqualToString:@"txt"]) {
            [myDictionary setObject:header forKey:@"header"];
        }
        if ([header isEqualToString:@"pic"]) {
            [myDictionary setObject:header forKey:
             @"header"];
        }
        if ([header isEqualToString:@"voc"]) {
            [myDictionary setObject:header forKey:@"header"];
        }

        [myDictionary setObject:msgArray forKey:@"content"];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"MessageCome" object:nil userInfo:myDictionary];

        MQTTClient_freeMessage(&message);
        MQTTClient_free(payloadptr);

        return 1;
    }
```

The Xcode throw out`-[__NSArrayM length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17dc7bb0`
and `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17dc7bb0'`

What on earth the problem is?

Any help should be appreciate!

More

```
 - (void)handle:(NSNotification *)notification
    {
        NSDictionary *message = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[notification userInfo]];
        NSString *msgType = [message objectForKey:@"header"];
        if ([msgType isEqualToString:@"txt"]) {
            NSArray *array = [message objectForKey:@"content"];
            NSString *msg = [[array valueForKey:@"description"] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
            [self.messages addObject:msg];
            NSLog(@"%@&%lu", msg, (unsigned long)[self.messages count]);
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self.tableView reloadData];
            });

        }
        if ([msgType isEqualToString:@"pic"]) {
            // process pic
        }
        if ([msgType isEqualToString:@"voc"]) {
            [self.messages addObject:[message objectForKey:@"content"]];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self.tableView reloadData];
            });
        }
    }
```

Here is my observer

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handle:) name:@"MessageCome" object:nil];



    context void *  NULL    0x00000000
topicName   char *  "/test" 0x16dcbe24
*topicName  char    '/' '/'
topicLen    int 0   0
message MQTTClient_message *    0x16dcc064  0x16dcc064
struct_id   char [4]    ""  
struct_version  int 4   4
payloadlen  int 28675   28675
payload void *  0x4409004   0x04409004
qos int 1   1
retained    int 0   0
dup int 0   0
msgid   int 25864   25864
payloadptr  void *  0x4409004   0x04409004
payLoadLen  int 28675   28675
msgArray    __NSArrayM *    @"1 object" 0x16dcc280
[0] NSURL * @"file:///var/mobile/Applications/417171BD-60C5-4DF6-989D-2983426B9CAD/Library/Documentationsound.wav"  0x16dd0760
dataHeader  _NSInlineData * 3 bytes 0x16d48420
strEncode   NSStringEncoding    4   4
header  __NSCFString *  @"voc"  0x16dca530
myDictionary    __NSDictionaryM *   2 key/value pairs   0x16dd0830
[0] (null)  @"content" : @"1 object"    
[1] (null)  @"header" : @"voc"  
content NSData *    nil 
msgContent  NSString *  nil 
subStr  NSString *  nil 
voiceData   NSMutableData * nil 
fm  NSFileManager * nil 
voicePath   NSString *  nil 
voiceURL    NSURL * nil
```

This is my tableView dataSource

```
    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return [self.messages count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
        cell.textLabel.text = [self.messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }


    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Update you question with execution stack using BT commend on debugger.

Comment: @iAmbitious Sorry, I do not understand.

Comment: Which line is the exception thrown on?

Comment: @Wain     autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([FWAppDelegate class])); I think Xcode is not very helpful this time.

Comment: Please show the declaration of `MQTTClient_message`.

Comment: By the way - that is terrible code.  Why is there a separate `free` call for `message` and `message->payload`? Why are you even calling `free` within *that* method at all? Why are you passing pointer-to-pointer in the first `free` call?  Why not use an `enum` for these different types, instead of a string?  Why call `if`, rather than `else if` to test the same variable?

Comment: If the problem is memory related you might find it if you [enable NSZombie](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386160/how-to-enable-nszombie-in-xcode)

Comment: @MatthiasBauch I've done that, doesn't work.

Comment: @trojanfoe I just use the IBM's MQTT library. The documentation about how to build a MQTT client is written in C, and I imitate that with objective-C. I consider so many free is about the memory management. Sample code:http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.mq.javadoc.doc%2FWMQMQxrCClasses%2Fpubasync.html      The declaration of MQTTClient_message is not showed in the page. Please download the SDK, it is right there.

Comment: That's fair enough; it's IBM writing crap code rather than you.  However my other points stand.  If you use an `enum` to identify the messages, you can use a `switch` statement, which will be easier to follow.

Comment: Add damn breakpoint and paste a line which crashes - why it's so hard for you ? :DDDD

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski I did what you said,  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"MessageCome" object:nil userInfo:myDictionary]; when I step into the notification, it crashed.

Comment: Post code from there - from the function which is reacting on that message

Comment: That `object:nil` looks wrong...

Comment: Nope, object:nil is just fine.

Comment: Well it's not causing this error, however it's usual to provide that information if an observer has asked to be notified for all messages sent by a particular object.  There is no reason to pass `nil`.

Comment: So on which line it stops exactly ? Can you post also stack trace ?

Comment: Ok, object:nil is not a good practice.

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski hanlde:notification is not been executed. Whether I step over or step into postNotification, it will crash.

Comment: Why are you stepping into it?  Put a breakpoint at the start of the handler; you shouldn't be interested in *how* the notification is posted, only how it's handled (i.e. just your code).

Comment: @trojanfoe ...It crashed at [self.tableView reloadData]

Comment: Is there a chance you can just post that project somewhere ? That would be easiest

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski OK, wait, I'll post it to Github

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski it's best if all the relevant code is posted here, if possible, to keep the question self contained.  Anyway, we finally got there, we have enough of the code to diagnose the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the error:

```
if ([msgType isEqualToString:@"voc"]) {
    [self.messages addObject:[message objectForKey:@"content"]];   // HERE
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    });
}
```

As you've already shown that `@"content"` is an array:

```
myDictionary    __NSDictionaryM *   2 key/value pairs   0x16dd0830
[0] (null)  @"content" : @"1 object"    // HERE
[1] (null)  @"header" : @"voc"
```

And your table code expects it to be a string:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [self.messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Hence the *unrecognised selector* error, as the label's text is expected to be an `NSString` object and not an `NSArray` object.

Note the difference in how you populate your data source for `@"voc"` and `@"txt"` type messages.

Comment: @JeremyP yeah it took long enough to get all the required info.  Cheers.

Comment: @AlexSteven You're not "out of the woods" yet though.  I think this line will cause issues too: `[[array valueForKey:@"description"]`.

Comment: @trojanfoe Indeed, this line works well, but I also think it is not a good practice. Cause I have to mix objective-C with C, I have no idea how to take characters out of the array. The message delivered by MQTT is defined as void *

Comment: @AlexSteven Sounds like a new question then.

Comment: @trojanfoe Uh-oh... Great programmer, you have a lot of reputation. I thought it means nothing to you. LOL

Answer (score 1):

To get size of NSMutableArray you need to call:

```
 [array count]
```

not length

The error tells you are calling "length" on a NSMutableArray class - this is why it crashes.
It's not in the code you pasted - so best put a exception breakpoint and check from which line it is coming.

Comment: As I advice - add exception breakpoint and find it :) I'm no a miracle to tell you that without whole project sources. It's definitely not in the part you pasted.

Comment: So this is more general advice than a concise answer?

Comment: its run time miracle, questioner treating somewhere array data but he did not getting array instead of he got NSString.

Comment: No - I gave you concrete answer pointing you the problem you have. It's nothing about ARC or memory. You are just calling a method on wrong class. Post the whole project than I can help you - or just use that expection breakpoint - it will stop exactly in the line you are doing things wrong - and that's general advice, but it will solve your problem

Comment: My bet is that something receives the notification and takes the array from the userInfo dictionary but the code casts it to an NSString.

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski Are you confusing me with the OP?  Your answer is pointless; 90% of people here know what *unrecognised selector* errors mean and the other 10% should be directed towards the 1000-odd questions on the subject which litter SO.

Comment: Say what ?... Did you just tried using exception breakpoint instead of wasting time for such long comments ? :) Do it and paste a code, function which crashes, instead of having that pointless discussion.

Comment: It's probably not a writing problem of the OP (I hope he did not write `[array length]` in his code). But it's a good advice since, the zombie pointer seems to be a string that try to call `length`

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski What?  Me?  I am not the OP!!!  If your answer is "set an expection breakpoint" then that is a comment and not an answer.

Comment: No my answer is you are calling length instead of count on an array. This is an answer. Breakpoint is an advice how to find where it is happening.

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski Me?  you do not understand that I **did not ask this question** do you?

Comment: @DavidCaunt Yes, my method handle the notification do cast it to an NSString, what the problem is?

Comment: Add exception breakpoint and show a function which breaks - how many times I have give that advice....

Answer (score 1):

This line (in `msgarrvd`)

```
[myDictionary setObject:msgArray forKey:@"content"];
```

sets the content key of a dictionary to an array (a mutable one in fact).

This line (in the notification handler)

```
[self.messages addObject:[message objectForKey:@"content"]]
```

takes the object for the content key (an array remember) and adds it to the `messages` array.

This line (in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`)

```
cell.textLabel.text = [self.messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

takes an object from the `messages` array (which was itself an array, remember) and tries to assign it to a property called `text` which is expected to be a string.  Then somewhere inside the Cocoa library something wants to find out how long the string is, but it is not a string, it's an array and arrays don't respond to `-length`.

Comment: That's right - this is where it's kicking in. Good find ;) hope my pushing for breakpoint helped :D

Comment: Actually, @trojanfoe seems to have got there first with the right answer.